# Указатели в языке Си

Tags: c, функции, указатели

Написать программу, которая копировала бы строку введѐнную пользователем с
клавиатуры в новую (максимальная длина строки - 20 символов). При этом в
процессе копирования должны отбрасываться все незначащие пробелы в начале и
конце строки, а также несколько подряд идущих пробелов должны заменяться на
один. Вывести исходную и новую строки на экран. Для обхода строк использовать
указатели (запрещено использовать библиотечную функцию `strcopy()`).

**Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в коде**
(
Не понимаю такие моменты как:

```
if(space && *p == ' ') p++;
        else
        {
            space = (*p == ' ');
            *dst++ = *p++;
        }
    }
    if(p != src && *(dst - 1) == ' ') dst--;
    *dst = 0;
      
)
 
if(space && *p == ' ') p++;
*dst++ = *p++;

)
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
void scpy(const char *src, char *dst) {
    const char *p = src;
    int space = 1;
    while(*p)
    {
        if(space && *p == ' ') p++;
        else
        {
            space = (*p == ' ');
            *dst++ = *p++;
        }
    }
    if(p != src && *(dst - 1) == ' ') dst--;
    *dst = 0;
}
 
int main()
{
    const char *src = "    Quick    brown    fox     ";
    char dst[100];
    scpy(src, dst);
    printf("%s\n", src);
    printf("%s\n", dst);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объясняю работу `scpy()`:

1. Параметры: `const char* src`, элементы которого нельзя изменить(нам это и запрещено, модифицировать будем только `dst`) и  `char* dst` куда будет копироваться `src`.
2. `const char* p = src;` создаем указатель, который указывает на `src`.
3. `int space = 1;` отслеживаем наличие пробелов
4. Дальше цикл который копирует значение из `src` в `dst`:

- Пока не встретим окончание строки `while(*p != '\0')`
- Проверяем, если в текущей позиции есть пробел -> заставляем указатель указывать на следующий символ.
- Иначе,  `space = (*p == ' ');` в скобках смотрим что лежит по текущему адресу, если это пробел, то присваиваем  `space = 1` истину, иначе - `0`
- Давайте проанализируем `*(dst++) = *(p++);`: приоритет у постфиксного инкремента выше. Выражение в скобках будет первой выполняться, но`dst` и `p` увеличены будут не сразу, только в конце. Потом копирование происходит. А вот уже сейчас те указатели инкрементируються!
- `if(p != src && *(dst - 1) == ' ') dst--;` `p != src` - это может быть когда мы не зашли в цикл и передали пустую строку. `(dst - 1)` потому, что последний символ - `\0`, а нам нужно проверять что перед ним. Далее `dst--` чтоб не указывал на пробел.
- И в конце добавляем нуль-терминатор, чтоб `printf()` знал когда остановиться

Comment: `const char* src` Вообще-то все это можно, нельзя только изменить адрес на который указывает указатель... Т.к. `const char *` эквивалент нормальной записи `char const *`.

Comment: `const char * `эквивалент нормальной записи `char const *` с этим я согласен, но изменить адрес на который указывает `const char*` можно, но значение элементов поменять нельзя!

Comment: а вот уже `char const* ` заставить указывать на другое нельзя, зато значения элементов изменять можно

Comment: ... Вы ничего не поняли... Я сказал, что нельзя изменить адрес на который он указывает, т.е. его значение менять можно, как и всех элементов, если есть доступ на запись на самом деле. https://ideone.com/gJtxn8

Comment: спасибо вам огромное,очень выручили!